# winning the match (which is first to win n games), if i know the probability of them winning a game?

Tags: probability

Say i have two players who each have a certain probability of winning a game,
for example for player $1$: $p_1=0.8$ and player $2$: $p_2=0.2$.
There are $n$ games in a match, what is the probability of player $1$ being the first to win $n$ games,and therefore win the match?
Thanks.

Comment: Hint:  Suppose they play out $2n-1$ games (just as the World Series has $7$, though usually they aren't all played).  That is, suppose they play all those game regardless of whether or not a winner is settled.  Clearly exactly one side will have won $n$ or more games, so the winner is unchanged.

Comment: To be clear:  I don't believe there is a simple closed formula for the answer.  Just sum up the probability that $1$ wins exactly $n$, exactly $n+1$, and so on.    If $n$ is big enough you can use a normal approximation, but if $n$ is small (as it usually is in this context) then you just have to do the sum.

Comment: ok i will try that out, thanks alot :)

Comment: hi there, when do i stop doing the sum?

Comment: The posted solution, from @rlartiga , seems complete.  The least number of games the winner will win is $n$, the most is $2n-1$.

Answer (score 3):

**Calculus for a fixed number of games**

If both play a total of $m$ games, then $n$ games must be won for the first player with probability $p$ each one, being them independent:
$$p^n$$
The second player must won $m-n$ games. That with probability $1-p$ each one.
$$(1-p)^{m-n}$$
Finally to conclude the game the last one must be won by the first player, so we must choose from $m-1$ games which $n-1$ to be won.
$${m-1 \choose n-1}$$
So the probability is:
$$P(x=m)={m-1 \choose n-1} p^n(1-p)^{m-n}$$

**Calculus for the total of games:**

The constraint in the number of games is that the second player must win no game or at most $n-1$ so:
$$0\leq m-n \leq n-1$$
$$n\leq m \leq 2n-1$$

So adding up:

$$\sum_{k=n}^{2n-1}P(x=k)=\sum_{k=n}^{2n-1} {k-1 \choose n-1} p^n(1-p)^{k-n}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} {k+n-1 \choose n-1} p^n(1-p)^{k}$$

**If $n=2$:**

$$\sum_{k=2}^{3}P(x=k)=\sum_{k=2}^{3} {k-1 \choose 1} p^{2}(1-p)^{k-2}$$
$$=\sum_{k=2}^{3} (k-1) p^{2}(1-p)^{k-2}=(3-2p)p^2$$

As you can see that is not greater than one.

Comment: ok i will try that out :) thanks

Comment: out of interest what is this method called?

Comment: @whatsupdoc It looks like a Binomial Distribution.

Comment: i'm not sure how this would show which player wins first, could someone explain to me please? :)

Comment: @whatsupdoc here goes the explanation in the answer.

Comment: would you mind showing how you would sub in values and calculate because i have been  trying n = 2 but get an answer at the end which is greater than one?

Comment: @whatsupdoc my answer is updated to cover your question.